# Download Hidden Google Drive data with php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to download hidden whatsapp data from Google Drive.

Thanks to Tomers useful instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832104/see-hidden-app-data-in-google-drive/36487545#36487545?newreg=f8e85ba11c64409da79ca9cf2124d676) (Thanks!) I can see the data but I'm quite flummoxed how to download it. My main problem is I can't identify a direct link and I can't get my head around the coding to request one.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each file inside the hidden Google Drive directory has an ID, which you can see via `$file->getId()`. (In my example you have linked, the ID is shown in parentheses next to each file name)
Then, downloading the file should be as simple as

```
$fileId = '1kTFG5TmgIGTPJuVynWfhkXxLPgz32QnPJCe5jxL8dTn0';
$content = $service->files->get($fileId, array('alt' => 'media' ));
file_put_contents("result_file.crypt9",$content);
```

Also take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads).